# Stability and simplicity of tangent sheaf of Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, grassmannians, coherent-sheaves

Everything is over the complex numbers. Let $ X = \text{Gr}(k,n) $ be a Grassmannian variety and with tangent sheaf $ T_X $.

(1) Is $ T_X $ simple, i.e. is $\text{Hom} (  T_X,  T_X) = \mathbb{C} $?

(2) Is $ T_X $ (slope) stable?

Motivation: If (1) is true then $ T_X $ cannot split as a sum of two vector bundles of lower rank, akin to the famous example of $ T_{\mathbb{P}^2} $ which is proved rather easily using Chern classes. (2) is of course, stronger than (1).

Comment: (1) is true, and follows for instance from Borel-Bott-Weil theorem.

Comment: @Sasha could you elaborate please? I thought Borel-Weil-Bott gives the cohomology of certain line bundles. How does (1) follow?

Comment: There is an extension of BBW to irreducible equivarant vector bundles on arbitrary $G/P$, see for instance Section 3 in [Kuznetsov, Alexander. Exceptional collections for Grassmannians of isotropic lines. Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. (3) 97 (2008), no. 1, 155--182].

Comment: One possible starting point to the literature is https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2350.

Comment: Ok, if someone posts an answer with a short summary of keywords from which it follows, I'll accept it.